# React Js: Getting and error in if else statement Line 50:20: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

Hey guys I am very new to React and was following a tutorial about hooks and wanted to try it out, I don't know the code is correct as of now as I am getting error in the if statement condition to check the logged in state. This is the error that pops up.

```
./src/components/Header.js
Line 50:20:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  48 | 
  49 |     return (
> 50 |       {if(loggedIn === true) {
     |                    ^
  51 |         return (
  52 |           <React.Fragment>
  53 |             <CssBaseline />
```

This is the Header.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
// import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    appBar: {
        borderBottom: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
        minHeight: 100,
        background : '#1e202c',
    },

    toolbar: {
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    color: 'white',
    },

    toolbarTitle: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        color: 'white',

    },
    link: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1, 1.5),
    },
}))

function Header() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [logState, setLogState] = useState({
      loggedIn: false,
    })

    useEffect(() => {
      if (sessionStorage.getItem('jwt')) {
        setLogState({ loggedIn: true });
      }
      

    }, [setLogState]);

    return (
      {if(loggedIn === true) {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <CssBaseline />
              <AppBar position="fixed" color="default" elevation={0} className={classes.appBar}>
              <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
                <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap className={classes.toolbarTitle}>
                  TestWebsite
                </Typography>
                <nav>
                  <Link component={NavLink} variant="button" color="inherit" href="#" to= "/" className={classes.link}>
                    Home
                  </Link>
                  <Link variant="button" color="inherit" href="#" className={classes.link}>
                    Accounts
                  </Link>
                </nav>
                <Button component={NavLink} href="#" color="inherit" variant="outlined" to="/logout/" className={classes.link} >
                  Logout
                </Button>
              </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
          </React.Fragment>
          )
        } else {
          return (
            <React.Fragment>
            <CssBaseline />
              <AppBar position="fixed" color="default" elevation={0} className={classes.appBar}>
              <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
                <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap className={classes.toolbarTitle}>
                  TestWebsite
                </Typography>
                <nav>
                  
                </nav>
                <Button href="#" component={NavLink} color="inherit" variant="outlined"
                   to="/signup/" className={classes.link} >
                  SignUp
                </Button>
                <Button component={NavLink} href="#" color="inherit" variant="outlined" to="/login/" className={classes.link} >
                  Login
                </Button>
              </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
            </React.Fragment>
            )
        }
      }
        
    )
}

export default Header
```

Is this the correct way to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the return ({ }) around your isLoggedIn condition.
Also you should test logState.loggedIn instead of loggedIn

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, but now I am getting this error `Line 49:11:  'loggedIn' is not defined  no-undef`.

Comment: Just edited my answer, you should test logstate.loggedIn instead of loggedIn (there is no variable loggedIn declared in your code)

Comment: Can you also check my code and tell me why my else statement is not running? Even when I logout it shows the same header as logged in. Thanks

Comment: You are binding the useEffect to the setLogState function meaning that it will be run only on init and when setLogState changes (likely never). The setLogState should additionally be called upon logout action (after the logout action was successfully processed by your server for instance) and when you successfully logged in (when the server returns you the new jwt token)

Comment: So does that mean I have to use two useEffects for each login and logout action?

Comment: Without the logic for login/logout it's hard to tell. The naive way would be to have a method in your component `const handleLogin = (loggedIn) => {setLogState({loggedIn})}`. Then on the logIn button, `onclick={()=>handleLogin(true)}`, on the logOut button `onclick={()=>handleLogin(false)}`

But in more realistic scenarios, you are likely to have events on login and logout. In the useEffect you should subscribe to those and update the logState accordingly. Then useEffect should return a method that unsubscribe those subscriptions on component unmount

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `if` with ternary operator:

```
return loggedIn : Elem1 ? Elem2
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a needless `return` in the `Header`, try this

```js
function Header() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [logState, setLogState] = useState({
    loggedIn: false,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("jwt")) {
      setLogState({ loggedIn: true });
    }
  }, [setLogState]);

  if (logState.loggedIn === true) {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <CssBaseline />
        <AppBar
          position="fixed"
          color="default"
          elevation={0}
          className={classes.appBar}
        >
          <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
            <Typography
              variant="h6"
              color="inherit"
              noWrap
              className={classes.toolbarTitle}
            >
              TestWebsite
            </Typography>
            <nav>
              <Link
                component={NavLink}
                variant="button"
                color="inherit"
                href="#"
                to="/"
                className={classes.link}
              >
                Home
              </Link>
              <Link
                variant="button"
                color="inherit"
                href="#"
                className={classes.link}
              >
                Accounts
              </Link>
            </nav>
            <Button
              component={NavLink}
              href="#"
              color="inherit"
              variant="outlined"
              to="/logout/"
              className={classes.link}
            >
              Logout
            </Button>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        color="default"
        elevation={0}
        className={classes.appBar}
      >
        <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
          <Typography
            variant="h6"
            color="inherit"
            noWrap
            className={classes.toolbarTitle}
          >
            TestWebsite
          </Typography>
          <nav></nav>
          <Button
            href="#"
            component={NavLink}
            color="inherit"
            variant="outlined"
            to="/signup/"
            className={classes.link}
          >
            SignUp
          </Button>
          <Button
            component={NavLink}
            href="#"
            color="inherit"
            variant="outlined"
            to="/login/"
            className={classes.link}
          >
            Login
          </Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using conditionals using ternary operator if using js inside return

```
conditon(if true)?<Element1/>:<Element2/>
```